# Ruby shellwords retaining quotes on split

Tags: ruby, string, split, quoting

Given arbitrary strings that I need to split into tokens, I'm using [`Shellwords`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) to retain quoted tokens intact.  However, in the process the quotation marks (or apostrophes) are lost.  What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
#method('this contains "a quoted" string')
=> ["this", "contains", "\"a quoted\"", "string"]
```

`#shellescape` doesn't seem to help because it returns something essentially unsplittable.

How can I retain the quotation marks (or apostrophes) as part of the token?  Do I need to pre-process the string somehow?  (Which kinda defeat the purpose of using `Shellwords`, ISTM.)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want the quotes to remain? _That_ seems to defeat the point of using Shellwords.

Comment: This screams "XY problem" to me. What's wrong with the result of `Shellwords.split(string) #=> ["this", "contains", "a quoted", "string"]` ? What are you trying to do with that array, which makes preserving the original quotes necessary?

Comment: For instance, what would you expect the result to be of `method('this contains "\"a quoted\"" string')`?

Comment: `Shellwords.split(string).map { |s| s[/[^\\]\s/] ? ['"', s, '"'].join : s }`

Comment: I want the quotes to be retained so that, for instance, I can write a command line back out to a shell script.  It's rather more complicated that that; I'm parsing `dhcpd` config files, which have very rigid definitions for syntax.  I'll check out the last suggestion shortly.

Comment: `'this contains "a quoted" string'.shellsplit.map(&:shellescape)` *almost* does it:
`=> ["this", "contains", "a\\ quoted", "string"]` -- but not quite.